# 1 line of code (console.log), two emplacement in the code = two results differents

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I encountered is with the jQuery Selector that returns me two different answers for the same line of code :

```
console.log($('.page_container')[3]);
```

In my navigation fonction using arrows of the keybord, this line would return me the content of this div including the parent '.page_container'.
This is exactly what I don't want since I need it as an object.

```
function checkKey(e) {
    var actualScroll = $('.main').scrollTop();
    var scrollTo = $('.page_container').height();
    console.log($('.page_container')[3]);
    if (e.keyCode == '38' && working == false) {
        working = true;
        // up arrow
        $(".main").animate({
            scrollTop: actualScroll - scrollTo,
        }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
            working = false;
        });
    } else if (e.keyCode == '40' && working == false) {
        working = true;
        // down arrow
        $(".main").animate({
            scrollTop: actualScroll + scrollTo,
        }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
            working = false;
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    //ArrowsNavigations
    document.onkeydown = testArrows;
});
```

But anywhere else in the code, it would return me the normal thing, the object version with all its original properties.

Edit :

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoshino78/x84urov9/1/) but I don't get why I don't have the same results, anyways on this fiddle whenever I select my entire array of '.page_container'  I get the object sample but if I select a particular index of this array I'll get the html of this occurence.
On my local version, the selector returns me the html content only when it's called in the checkKey function.

Comment: create a fiddle or share the whole code (including the other occurrences of this line of code).

Comment: What does `typeof $('.page_container')[3]` return?  It should be either 'undefined' or 'object'.  Do you want the jQuery-wrapped element or the native element?

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoshino78/x84urov9/1/) but I don't get why I don't have the same results, anyways on this fiddle whenever I select my entire array of '.page_container'  I get the object sample but if I select a particular index of this array I'll get the html of this occurence.
On my local version, the selector returns me the html content only when it's called in the checkKey function.

Comment: I think you do get an object. It's just the browser's way of displaying things. Try this: `console.log($('.page_container')[3].id);`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know why tough because it was returning me 'undefined' when I was trying this before ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do get an object. It's just the browser's way of displaying things.

Try this:

```
console.log($('.page_container')[3].id);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know why tough because it was returning me 'undefined' when I was trying this before ;) Thanks